# How to create List<Type>, where Type is another objects Type

Tags: .net, asp.net, umbraco

E.G

```
List<Node> myNodeList<node>();
System.Type theType = myNodeList.GetType();
IEnumerable list<theType> = myNodeList;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//original list
List<Node> nodeList = new List<Node>();

// just get the type of the list
var nodeListType = nodeList.GetType();

// Create a new type for a list containing the original list.
var genericType = typeof (List<>).MakeGenericType(nodeListType);

// and instantiate it.
var listOfLists = (IEnumerable)Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

You could also make a generic version:

```
public static IList<T> CreateOuterlist<T>(T innerList)
{
    return new List<T>();
}

List<Node> nodeList = new List<Node>();
var listOfLists = CreateOuterlist(nodeList);
listOfLists.Add(nodeList);
```